# Amazon EC2 Linux - Azure devops Agent installation throws an error while run config file

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, azure-devops

**./config.sh: line 85: ./bin/Agent.Listener: cannot execute binary file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

**The build agent does not support x64 based ARM (aarch64, arm64).** More details please take a look at this similar issue: [ARM agent fails to configure](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/552894/arm-agent-fails-to-configure.html)

---

The agent is based on .NET Core 2.1. You can run this agent on several Linux distributions. We support the following subset of .NET Core supported distributions:

x64

- CentOS 7, 6 (see note 1)
- Debian 9
- Fedora 30, 29
- Linux Mint 18, 17
- openSUSE 42.3 or later
- Oracle Linux 7
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8, 7, 6 (see note 1)
- SUSE Enterprise Linux 12 SP2 or later
- Ubuntu 18.04, 16.04

ARM32 (see note 2)

- Debian 9
- Ubuntu 18.04

Regardless of your platform, you will **need to install Git 2.9.0 or higher**. We strongly recommend installing the latest version of Git.

Not familiar with Amazon related product, however you need to make sure that environment meet all prerequisites above. Otherwise, the build agent could not be installed succeed. 
Update:

---

Besides, you could also give a try with some other environment to narrow down your issue. Also suggest you to use the [latest version](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases) of the agent.

More details please kindly refer our official tutorial here: [Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks, @patricklu-msft I have already installed git(2.17) in my server

Comment: Hi @BlueCloud Are you are able to use to the same account to install the agent on other server environment, like a  physical machine or Azure VM. This will narrow if this related to environment or your account or configuration,,, Sorry we do not have an Amazon environment to do a test.

Comment: Hi BlueCloud, how about this issue, did you finally figure out it?

Comment: No @patricklu-msft, I am not able to figure out this issue :(.

Comment: Hi @BlueCloud We found something new. Are you trying to install agent on an X64 based ARM system. If so, this is not support, the build agent does not support x64 based ARM (aarch64, arm64). Please take a look at this similar issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/552894/arm-agent-fails-to-configure.html

Comment: Yes @patricklu-msft, My server is X64 based ARM system, My other server is X86_64 based ARM system and the agent was working fine in this system. Thanks a lot :)